# Why Delete and Rename option is disabled on few items?

Tags: publishing, publishing-service, accessibility

I was trying to publish a few items from master to the web, but it always skips those items, Delete and rename options are also disabled for those items, I tried by moving items from master to web, it worked. but whenever I publish items again it deletes moved items from the web.

Comment: Check Publishing restrictions / Workflow status of those items. If they are not publishable then they won't be published... If delete/rename is disabled that check workflows as they might cause you this trouble. Never ever move items between master and web manually. You do not want to go that rabbit hole path...

Comment: Regarding Delete/Rename,apart from workflow state, Please check the access level permission.